# json_decode returns null

Tags: php, json

I store encoded arrays in a database, and when I try to decode it, it will return with null.

```
[{"id":13,"qty":"1"}]
```

Arrays are encoded with PHP, so I have no idea what the problem might be.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you are using, as the problem is likely to be in that...

Comment: Works fine, here's print_r(): `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13, [qty] => 1 ) )`

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: [Proof on codepad that it works](http://codepad.org/mkFSo4UK)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print:

```
json_last_error()
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally the `serialize();` and `unserialize();` functions would be better if you want to store an array in a database. JSON functions should be used for JSON strings to be returned to JavaScript.

```
$array = array('data','more data','superdata'=>'even more data');
$array = serialize($array);
// Store array in database after serialized
```

Then to turn the data back into an array from the database, you would...

```
// Fetch the data from the database
$data = $row['myDataArray'];
$array = unserialize($data);
echo $array['superdata']; // Would produce: "even more data"
```

Hopefully this will help you out a bit with your issues. If you did need to turn it into JSON to send to JavaScript, then you would use the `json_encode($array);` function.

Comment: "should" is a strong word here, especially since the JSON result is usually shorter than the `serialize()` result for basic types.

Comment: Well if you were to be storing a major amount of data, then it could make an impact. I just feel that serialize is more reliable and the best way to go when you are working with just PHP, not JavaScript JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though in a different context. In my case, I was trying to decode a JSON string, encoded with Javascript `JSON.stringify`, store it in a hidden text field and decode it back in PHP after the page is `POST`ed. I found, applying a stripslashes function before decoding was helpful.

```
$arrMyOutput = json_decode(stripslashes($yourJSON_string_goes_here));
```